# Why my two action buttons is not working and the delete modal is not showing? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
import Nav from "./Nav";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./css/table.css";
import "./css/modal.css";
import "./css/user-list.css";

const ManageUsers = () => {
  const [users] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('users')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))
      : []
  );
  const [loggedInData] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'))
      : []
  );
  const [chats] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('chats') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chats')) : []
  );
  const [uploads] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('uploads')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('uploads'))
      : []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loggedInData) {
      window.location.href = './welcome';
    }
    tableRows();
    addEmptyRows();
  }, []);

  const tableRows = () => {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
      trElement.innerHTML = `
        <tr>
          <td>${user.fullname}</td>
          <td>${user.email}</td>
          <td>
            <Link to={'./edituser?id=${user.id}'}>
              <button className='edit-delete2'>Edit</button>
            </Link>
            ${loggedInData.email === user.email ? '' : `|<button className="edit-delete2" id={delete-${user.id}} onClick=showDeleteModal${user.id}>Delete</button>
            `}
          </td>
        </tr>
      `;
      document.getElementById('table-body').appendChild(trElement);
    });
  };

  const addEmptyRows = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
      trElement.innerHTML = `
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      `;
      document.getElementById('table-body').appendChild(trElement);
    }
  };

  const showDeleteModal = (selectedId) => {
    document.getElementById("delete-modal-container").style.visibility =
      "visible";
    document.getElementById("ok-delete").addEventListener("click", () => {
      const selectedUserObj = users.find(({ id }) => id === +selectedId);
      users.splice(users.indexOf(selectedUserObj), 1);
      localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));

      const chatsUpdated = chats.filter(
        (chat) => chat.fullname !== selectedUserObj.fullname
      );
      localStorage.setItem("chats", JSON.stringify(chatsUpdated));

      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        const emailToMatch = users[i].email;
        const selectedUploadObj = uploads.find(`enter code here`
          (upload) => upload.user === emailToMatch
        ).user;
        if (selectedUploadObj) {
          const index = uploads.indexOf(selectedUploadObj);
          uploads.splice(index, 1);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("uploads", JSON.stringify(uploads));
      }
      tableRows();
      addEmptyRows();
    });
    showDeleteModal();
    hide();
  };

  const hide = () => {
    document.getElementById("delete-modal-container").style.visibility =
      "hidden";
  };

  const deleteUser = (id) => {
    showDeleteModal(id);
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="login-success">
      <Nav />
      <div className="users-header">
        <h2 className="user-p">Users</h2>
      </div>
      <table className="table-wrapper">
        <thead>
          <tr className="table-row-header">
            <td className="first-column-width">Name</td>
            <td className="second-column-width">User Email ID</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
      </table>
      <div className="delete-modal-container" id="delete-modal-container">
        <div className="confirm-deletion-wrapper">
          <p className="confirm-deletion-title">Confirm User Deletion</p>
          <button className="close-button-modal" onClick={hide}>
            ✕
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="delete-modal-mid-content">
          <img src="./img/question-mark.png" alt="question-mark-logo" />
          <span>Are you sure?</span>
        </div>
        <div className="delete-modal-button-wrapper">
          <Link to="/manageusers">
            <button className="modal-button" id="ok-delete" onClick={deleteUser}>
              Ok
            </button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/manageusers">
            <button className="modal-button" onClick={hide}>Cancel</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ManageUsers;
```

It has error manageusers:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: showDeleteModal1676598011384 is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

This JS code displays the users from the local storage but the action buttons are not functioning. The delete button is hidden in the current user. I am using dynamic id. Also its style didnt reflect on it. Here is the full project. Run it on VS code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DWdWh1Lmi-sooIUGK3yDhw3MuCEL31Jo/view?usp=sharing Thank you!

Comment: can you create a codesandbox where you can show the problem that you are facing

Comment: Hi! I cant post in sandbox but here is the gdrive link of the project. Try to register first for the local storage. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DWdWh1Lmi-sooIUGK3yDhw3MuCEL31Jo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: FYI, when you post your code somewhere you don't need to include node_modules. Eventually dev has to run `npm i`.